# Azure DevOps Server: How to view the overall workflow for a work item?

Tags: azure-devops, state, workflow, transition

I'm using Azure DevOps Server, Update 1.1. I'm working in a collection that's using the Inheritance process model.

I'm demonstrating a CMMI process template project to my product owners. For any one work item (e.g. a Change Request), I want to show them the overall state-transition workflow. For example, JIRA has a feature that lets you view the overall state-transition workflow for a work item (see screen shot below).

I'm not looking to edit or customize the workflow. I just want to see the overall state-transition workflow for a particular work item

Is there something equivalent to the JIRA feature in Azure DevOps Server?

[image]

Comment: Does Krzysztof's mentioned is help to you? If not, or any further puzzle with that, free to comment. I would help further info on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories?view=azure-devops&tabs=cmmi-process):

[image: Requirement workflow states, CMMI process]

Comment: Although this work flow is labeled "Requirement" (i.e., it's the workflow for the requirement work item type) it also appears to be the workflow for the Change Request work item type. I created a number of Change Request work item types and ran each through the workflow and the State/Reasons for the CR match the workflow for the Requirement work item. The workflows for all the work item types in the CMMI process template are probably the same. Microsoft should just say so in their docs :-)